# Asp.net Compressing pages problem

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7, compression

I have some pages in my web application that use Ms Ajax (update panel,script manager,...).when I want to add compressing module for my application I get this error :

```
ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
```

I searched in the internet and found that compressing has conflict with ms ajax.

Is there any way to solve that?  If I use IIS 7.x can I use compressing with that pages?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable compression by folder or mime type in IIS 7.  To disable compression for a single folder, browser to that folder in IIS, click Compression in the right pane and uncheck the checkmarks for Compress Static Content and Compress Dynamic Content.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833369/iis7-dynamic-content-compression-and-webservices) will show you how to enable/disable mime types at the server level if you wish to go that route.